# Как дать доступ к виртуальной камере flatpack приложениям на linux?

Tags: linux, fedora, flatpack

Есть виртуальная камера (от obs), но программы flatpack(skype, viber) не видят её. С параметром --device=all вроде видят её наличие, но картинки всё равно нету. v4l2loopback установлен. Веб версия скайпа через firefox (который не flatpack) всё видит. Так же есть странный баг: если в obs включить виртуальную камеру, а затем выключить, то опять включить до перезагрузки её не получиться. Obs так же установлена через flatpack. ОС - fedora 36 на wayland (на xorg всё так же).

P.S. возможно вопрос глупый, но в гугле я ничего не нашёл, а на fedor'у перешёл недавно, так что простите :)

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/sandbox-permissions.html#device-access

Пишут что пока только через опцию флэтпак `--device=all`

Comment: Так ни в какую не хочет работать. Просто чёрный квадратик в скайпе, а вайбер показывает вебку. А может быть есть возможность "открыть" ту "песочницу" flatpack'а?

Comment: А если флатпак прогу запустить с `sudo`?

Comment: он перемонтируется и чрутнится без девок

Comment: было бы хорошо, только с sudo флэтпаки не запускаются